# Mono Keepass2 Bugs / Errors in Entering Master Password via Paste or Using Backspace

Tags: mono

1. I repro'd this easily with Ubuntu 12.04 Keepass 2.18. I created a new file and saved to the desktop. Set master password as "test". When I close and reopen the same kdbx file, if I type in "text", works fine. If I hit  backspace after the last "t" and then retype "t", then hit "ok" I get the keyfile error, even though no keyfile is set and the password should be identical.
2. In Keepass2 on Ubuntu 12.04 I can NOT copy/paste into the Master Password field when first opening a database file if the copied text includes a symbol. When I paste a symbol characters like the degree symbol, °, it does not paste. Other characters seem to paste fine. The paste function appears in a rmb menu but when I do it nothing seems to happen? What's wrong?

UPDATE
I should note that on pasting passwords into new Keepass2 entries, I also see errant/spurious characters inserted (for example small rectangles). Seems like this may be related. Not sure it will effect most people since the password still pastes ok (paste omits the spurious characters in text fields), but perhaps it may affect other mono password fields used in Ubuntu. Obviously can also be confusing to the user.

create new entry
copy paste a password into password field
save/close/reopen entry
show password
small rectangles appended on end of password

Comment: you should take this question to the people developing keepass. If keepass2 isn't supported to run on mono you may have to live with unexpected and unintended behavior.

Comment: I did. They said these are mono issues and to report them to mono.

Comment: and what did the mono guys say?

Comment: They have not said anything on the matter. I posted to their "forum" and emailed their discussion group, nothing. Where do I get help? http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Mono-issues-in-Keepass2-tp4657133.html

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with buggy password characters when using Mono.

[Keepassx](https://www.keepassx.org/screenshots/) works better on Linux, it's cross platform and doesn't need Mono.

```
apt-get install keepassx
```